# In Germany: can i live in a Betriebstaette to circumvent payment of the Rundfrunkbeitrag

Tags: savings, law, germany

While for a flat a person has to pay 17 sth. € per month, while for a Betriebstätte with one person working a company only has to pay 5.99 €.

As the company doesn't have to pay anything at all if the Betriebstätte is a private flat, I got the idea to turn around this. So my Question is: Can I unsubscribe from the Rundfunkbeitrag by saying I live in a flat where someone else is paying (if this is a natural person it works) if this other party is a company?

Comment: Please explain what a Betriebstätte, sth. €, and Rundfunkbeitrag are.

Comment: € is the currency symbol for the Euro

Comment: They are specific termini used in concerning German law.
**Betriebstätte** is a place where people of a company work and **Rundfunkbeitrag** is fee every German household has to pay to finance the public media.
see http://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/ (German) for more information. But I'm afraid the question is to specific to get answered here. -.-

Comment: Should be doable, though they would require paperwork from you. And do not expect to being able to really get all this done within a year. The GEZ is notoriously slow. Personally, I am not sure, whether the 120 Euros saved per year are worth the trouble.

They would probably ask you to provide paperwork for the Betriebsstaette, so this has to be a valid company. And they might come and inspect the place. You know the people.

Not sure though whether they might not still consider it a flat, given that you have a bed and shower inside.

In German law there is this thing called Umgehungsgeschaeft

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible.

[Section 2](https://recht.nrw.de/lmi/owa/br_bes_text?anw_nr=2&gld_nr=2&ugl_nr=2251&bes_id=19124&aufgehoben=N#det313098) of the Rundfunkbeitragsstaatsvertrag orders every person living in a *Wohnung* (flat) to pay the Rundfunkbeitrag for the flat. Wohnung is then defined in [section 3](https://recht.nrw.de/lmi/owa/br_bes_text?anw_nr=2&gld_nr=2&ugl_nr=2251&bes_id=19124&aufgehoben=N#det313099).

Section 3(2) specifically excludes rooms in some kinds of Betriebsstätten from the definition (shortened translation by me):

> 1. rooms in a shared accommodation, such as barracks, refugee centers, boarding schools,
> 2. rooms in non-permanent living homes, such as nursing homes,
> 3. patient rooms in hospitals,
> 4. cells in prisons and
> 5. rooms for short stays, such hotel rooms, holiday flats, housing in seminar centers.

So unless you live in one of those, a reverse argument (argumentum e contrario) shows that you still need to pay for your flat.

Comment: damn it :) - so I need to figure out a way to turn my whole floor (6 flats) into one flat to get some savings :/
And thanks for the answer - I totally missed that the listing of non-flats was about Betriebstätten...